# Inner workings of PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering if there's a decent resource for finding the inner workings of PHP.

I have taken a look at the source, but a decent explanation would really help.

Some example questions I'd like answered.

How does a PHP script get interpreted into machine readable code?

How does it interact with Apache, how does apache collect the HTML response from PHP?

And other questions like that.

Comment: This book also covers some of the internals: http://www.amazon.com/Extending-Embedding-PHP-Sara-Golemon/dp/067232704X/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a bit outdated but I think you'll find this useful:

[PHP internals and the Zend API](http://php.net/manual/de/internals2.ze1.zendapi.php)

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at this thread on Reddit:

IAm finishing my PhD in compilers. I wrote a PHP compiler. AMA

http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/9rpa3/for_my_fellow_geeks_iam_finishing_my_phd_in/

including the related Google Tech Talk.

Comment: I can't see because Reddit is blocked from where I am currently, but if I recall that discussion is about something a bit different - he wrote a compiler that compiles PHP to native executables, rather than to bytecode as the standard PHP compiler does.

Comment: It looks like you're correct from reading the site:

http://phpcompiler.org/

However from being a reddit junkie it appears that Facebook will be open sourcing their runtime rewrite, so perhaps there will be useful  documentation that comes out of that:

http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/aw7ni/facebook_rewrites_php_runtime_will_open_source_on/

Answer (score 0):

The best book on te topic is Sara Golemon's *Extending and Embedding PHP*.

It uses PHP 5.1.0, but everything should be appliable to any 5.x. You can find information about changes to 5.3 (especially for namespaces) in the source code.

Answer (score -2):

The PHP website is http://php.net/. It has a lot of information.

Comment: Say that something has a lot of information and don't address to a single resource is purism.